# how to keep old image when use update codeigniter 3?

Tags: image, file-upload, codeigniter-3, updates

The below code is working, but i am looking in case if the user did not choose a new photo then the code will not update the current image. The below code when i click on the update button (and keep the file upload empty) it show no image but currently there are an old image into table and image file.

controller :

```
public function update()
{

    $id = $this->input->post('id_laporan');
    $jenis_laporan = $this->input->post('jenis_laporan');
    $jenis_hewan = $this->input->post('jenis_hewan');
    $deskripsi = $this->input->post('deskripsi');
    $lokasi = $this->input->post('lokasi');
    $nama_pelapor = $this->input->post('nama_pelapor');
    $no_hp = $this->input->post('no_hp');
    $gambar = $_FILES['gambar']['name'];
    if ($gambar = '') {} else{
        $config ['upload_path'] = './upload';
        $config ['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar')){
            echo "Gambar gagal di Upload";
        }else{
            $gambar=$this->upload->data('file_name');
        }
    }
```

view :

```
  <form action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/data_barang/update';?>"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nama Barang</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_barang" class="form-control"
            value="<?php echo $brg->nama_barang?>">
        </div>

        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Keterangan</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_brg" class="form-control"
            value="<?php echo $brg->id_brg?>">
            <textarea type="text" name="keterangan" class="form-control"
            value="<?php echo $brg->keterangan?>"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kategori</label>
                <select type="text" name="kategori" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $brg->kategori?>">>
                    <option>makanan</option>
                    <option>peralatan</option>
                </select>
                
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Harga</label>
            <input type="text" name="harga" class="form-control"
            value="<?php echo $brg->harga?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Stok</label>
            <input type="text" name="stok" class="form-control"
            value="<?php echo $brg->stok?>">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Upload</label>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().'/upload/'.$brg->gambar ?>" class="card-img-top">
            <input type="file" name="gambar" class="file-styled">
        
        </div>

             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-3"> Simpan</button>
             <?php echo anchor('admin/data_barang/index','<div class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-3"> Kembali </div>') ?>  
     
    

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The below code when i click on the update button (and keep the file upload empty) it show no image

Because you set the **required** option for the file input field:

`<input type="file" name="gambar" required class="form-control">`